# Boost graph recursive template problem

Tags: c++, templates, boost-graph

Hi I have a boost graph like:

```
struct Vertex;
struct Edge;



typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, Vertex, Edge> Graph_t;


struct Vertex {
};

struct Edge {
    typedef std::vector<Graph_t::vertex_descriptor> intermediate_vertices_t;
    intermediate_vertices_t intermediate_vertices;
};
```

The problem is with the recursive template in the Edge class. I need to store a vector of vertices.

Comment: Are you sure that you've got the template parameters of your `Graph_t` right? The 4th and 5th parameters are _properties_, not the vertex and edge classes themselves... You have to provide a suitable container for the vertex and edge collections, and `boost::adjacency_list::vertex_descriptor` just points to the value type of that container (more or less).

Comment: What compiler you use. I've complied and run your code in VC++ 2010 without any problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a small wrapper class like:

```
typedef Graph_t::vertex_descriptor vd_t;                           

struct iVertexWrap{                                                
    iVertexWrap(vd_t v) : v(v)
    {}                                                             
    vd_t v;
};
```

forward declaring it before the Edge class.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`adjacency_list_traits`](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list_traits.html) to get around this problem. This class allows the user access to the vertex and edge descriptor types without requiring the user to provide the property types for the graph.

```
struct Vertex {
};

typedef boost::adjacency_list_traits<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS>::vertex_descriptor VertexDescriptor;
struct Edge {
    typedef std::vector<VertexDescriptor> intermediate_vertices_t;
    intermediate_vertices_t intermediate_vertices;
};
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, Vertex, Edge> Graph_t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `adjacency_list`:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html